# Merge 2 columns from datatable in datatextfield from dropdownlist

Tags: c#, .net

```
var id = Session["staff_id"].ToString()

//I have datatable with 5 columns

DataTable dt = function_return_Datatable(id);

dropdownlist1.DataSource = dt;

/*in DataTextField I want to merge two columns of DataTable, dt.columns [1] is First Name and dt.columns [2] is LastName*/

//I tried this way to merge them, but no results
dropdownlist1.DataTextField = dt.Columns[1].ToString()+" "+dt.Columns[2].ToString();

dropdownlist1.DataValueField = dt.Columns[0].ToString();
dropdownlist1.DataBind();
```

Any ideas for how to merge these two columns?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You'll need a full name column in your data table as DataTextField can refer to only one single field:

```
DataTable dt = function_return_Datatable(id);
dt.Columns.Add("FullName", typeof(string), "FirstName + ' ' + LastName");

dropdownlist1.DataSource = dt;
dropdownlist1.DataTextField = "FullName";
dropdownlist1.DataValueField = "ID";
dropdownlist1.DataBind();
```

Should do it

(you could also add this column in your SQL query)

Comment: @Alex, you seem to be new on StackOverflow, if you find an answer valid, you can up vote it by using the up arrow. Among the multiple answers you might receive for your question, you can select the most appropriate one by clicking on the check mark. I'm not looking for reputation but just to let you know... Welcome :)